# In hadoop, I just want to execute my own custom program on each node

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, distributed-computing

Yes, I want to run my custom program on each hadoop node.
I want to deploy No mapper and reducer.
It is just like distributed computing system that doesn't works like mapreduce(but which uses hdfs internally).
How should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both MapReduce and Tez jobs use YARN (Yet Another Resource Negotiator) to get distributed and executed over the cluster in so-called containers. You can also use YARN yourself to run your own jobs instead. Please take a look at the [Hadoop Architecture Overview](http://ercoppa.github.io/HadoopInternals/HadoopArchitectureOverview.html) for a high-level overview.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use map reduce you can use Apache tez https://tez.apache.org .you just need to install Apache tez over  Apache yarn just like  in MR .